# Kotlin reflection + generics

Tags: java, generics, reflection, kotlin

**EDIT 1:** Changed title, my bad.

I have an interface **Event**:

```
interface Event
```

And some classes that implement it, like **CustomEvent**:

```
class CustomEvent : Event { ... }
```

What I've been trying to do now is: given a method that has an event as a parameter (so, any class that implements the **Event** interface), like this

```
fun onCustomEvent(event: CustomEvent) {
    ...
}
```

, I want to add that event to a list. Thus, this list will end up holding a bunch of different events.

---

In **Java** I belive it would be something like this (might not be 100% accurate):

```
List<Class<? extends Event>> eventsList;

....

Class<?> param = methodThatHasSomeEventAsParam.parameterTypes[0];

if (Event.class.isAssignableFrom(param)) {
    Class<? extends Event> actualParam = (Class<? extends Event>) param;
    eventsList.add(actualParam); // Adds CustomEvent to the events list.
}
```

---

But as for Kotlin, I'm really not sure how to use the generics properly, specifically what would be the correct way to translate

```
Class<? extends Event>
```

to Kotlin, keeping the same behaviour as the Java code above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a nutshell, the equivalent of Java `<? extends Event>` is `<out Event>`. Does it solve your problem? If not, it would be easier to also see your Kotlin code. Also, see the [*Generic Variance*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance) section of the reference to learn about Kotlin generics if interested.

Comment: Woah, actually it did solve! I had been reading through the docs already, and had already tried <out Event>. But after reading your comment I tried again and just noticed a foolish error elsewhere that wouldn't make it work... Thank you! :)

Comment: @Frank You might even post an answer clarifying how it solves it so that if others ever stumble upon your question they might benefit from the clarity you've gained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the help; this would be the way to do it in Kotlin:

```
// <? extends Event> in Java ==> <out Event> in Kotlin.
val myList: MutableList<Class<out Event>>

val param: Class<*> = methodThatHasSomeEventAsParam.parameterTypes[0]

if (Event::class.java.isAssignableFrom(param)) {
    param as Class<out Event>
    myList.add(param)
}
```